# Reference on proof of these 3 theorems in Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, reference-request

I am taking a topology course this semester and I am not able to completely understand these proofs from my class notes.

(1)Show that $H_0(X)= R\pi_0(X)$.

Here $H_0(X)= H_0( C^{Sing}(X))$ but how to compute $H_0( C^{Sing}(X))$.

(2) If $f\simeq_H g$ , then $C^{Sing}(f) \simeq C^{Sing}(g)$.

(3) is Theorem of U-small chains:[image]

Question: Can you please give a reference of some book in Topology which contains proof of these 3 theorems. I don't think Hatcher's book on algebraic topology has these proofs. ( Atleast I couldn't find them)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Hatcher's Proposition 2.7 answers the question about computing $H_0(X)$.

(2) Hatcher's Theorem 2.10 (and its proof) provide this.

(3) This is Hatcher's Proposition 2.21.